# Adding attribute to second child in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Can someone please tell me how to add "top" attribute to the second "canvas" tag which is without id in div and which will work for IE using jquery or anything else. Following is the HTML snippet.

```
<div id="jqChart" class="ui-jqchart" style="height: 300px;">
<canvas width="841" height="300" style="position: relative;"></canvas>
<canvas width="794" height="222" style="position: relative; left: 37px; top: 42px;">        </canvas>
<div class="ui-jqchart-tooltip" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#jqChart > canvas:nth-child(2)").attr('top', 'yourValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("#jqChart > canvas:nth-child(2)").attr("attribute_name", "attribute_value");
```

just replace *attribute_name* and *attribute_value* with whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#jqChart>canvas:eq(1)").css("top", "1px");
```

Or,

```
$("#jqChart>canvas").eq(1).css("top", "1px");
```

Note that in `eq(n)`, n is zero-based. An alternative asolution with `nth-child` might look like

```
$("#jqChart>canvas:nth-child(2)").css("top", "1px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the second canvas element with the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method (which returns the element at the specified index, starting from 0, from the matched set of elements):

```
var canvas = $("#jqChart canvas").eq(1);
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by `top` attribute. I think you might be referring to the `top` CSS property, in which case you want the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
canvas.css("top", "100px");
```

If you do actually mean the `top` attribute, then look at the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

You could alternatively use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, but that's slower than the `.eq` method.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can do it with

```
$('#jqChart > canvas:last').attr('top', 'attr_value');
```